# Null Riemann tensor implies no gravity proof?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, curvature

It's easy to show that no gravity implies a null Riemann tensor, but how could I prove that a null R. tensor implies no gravity?

Comment: By the phrase “no gravity”, do you mean $\Gamma _{\alpha \beta }^{\sigma }=0$?

Comment: @BertBarrois careful! The Christoffel symbols can be zero even in flat spacetime. For example in polar coordinates there are non-zero Christoffel symbols. It just means the coordinates are curved.

Comment: I guess it depends on exactly how you want to define *no gravity*. Actually that's a surprisingly subtle question since even in flat spacetime you could be using curved coordinates.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I think 'flat spacetime' is usefully equivalent to 'no gravity'.  Choice of coordinate systems can't affect anything physical.  (But now you're going to point out I'm wrong and I'll feel silly :-))

Comment: @tfb Isn't acceleration gravity according to the equivalence principle?

Comment: @safesphere: acceleration is indistinguishable from gravity *locally* (to be precise: at a point): if you can make measurements over a region of spacetime then no, it's not.  An accelerated observer in flat spacetime can tell, if they can make measurements over a region of spacetime, that the spacetime they are in is flat.  That's why SR works for accelerated observers, for instance.

Comment: @tfb Or, gravity due to acceleration is locally equivalent to gravity of a heavy mass. By making measurements over a region of space, we can tell what type of gravity we have. Gravity is a force seen by an observer accelerating away from his timelike geodesic. Whether this geodesic is straight or curved does not change the nature of gravity. No?

Comment: @tfb: my view would be that *flat spacetime* and *no gravity* are different ways of saying the same thing so the distinction between them is specious. But suppose you're floating in space, how would you define *no gravity*. About the only criterion I can think of is *no tidal forces*. In the absence of infinite massive planes I can't think of any gravitational field that has no tidal forces.

Comment: @JohnRennie: yes I think that's right.  In particular the no-tidal-force thing is equivalent to flat spacetime I think.  And it is a measurement you can do, so it's not just a theoretical distinction, it's something you can measure (unless you are pointlike!).

Comment: by no gravity I mean that the mapping (boosting) from my coordinates to the minkowski space can be a global transformation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/385727/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A curved spacetime can be measured by the geodesic deviation. You set up a family of closely spaced geodesics indexed by a continuous variable $s$ and parameterized by the proper time $\tau$ (massive particle) or an affine parameter $\lambda$ (massless particle, e.g. photon).

You define a tangent vector to the geodesic $T^\mu = \partial x^\mu (s, \tau) / \partial \tau$ and a deviation vector $X^\mu = \partial x^\mu (s, \tau) / \partial s$, which is the displacement of two objects travelling along two infinitesimally separated geodesics.

The relative acceleration $A^\mu$ of the two objects is defined as the second derivative of the separation vector $X^\mu$ as the objects advance along their respective geodesics. Specifically you take the directional covariant derivative of $X$ along $T$ twice: $A^\mu = T^\alpha \nabla_\alpha (T^\beta \nabla_\beta X^\mu)$.

If you work out the formula you get the geodesic deviation equation: $A^\mu = R^\mu_{\nu \rho \sigma} T^\nu T^\rho X^\sigma$, where $R^\mu_{\nu \rho \sigma}$ is the Riemann tensor.

A zero Riemann tensor means a zero acceleration, that is a flat spacetime.

Note: The geodesic deviation equation is also known as the Jacobi equation.