# What exactly is the difference between a Ricci-flat manifold and Minkowski space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

Minkowski space describes a flat spacetime and a Ricci-flat manifold is a solution of GRT without curvature. Shouldn't they be the same? So, what's the difference?

Comment: *A Ricci-flat manifold is a solution of GRT without curvature.* No, it isn’t.

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/385727/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 8):

A flat spacetime has a zero Riemann tensor, while a Ricci flat spacetime has a zero Ricci tensor.

The Ricci tensor is a contraction of the Riemann tensor, and it is possible for the Ricci tensor to be zero when the Riemann tensor is not. An obvious example of this is the Schwarzschild geometry that describes a static black hole. In this geometry the Ricci tensor is zero everywhere but the spacetime is most certainly not flat.

Comment: Is this somewhat similiar to a tube that has no inner curvature but an outer curved topology?

Comment: No. The Ricci tensor on its own does not fully describe a geometry. It describes only one aspect of the geometry - roughly it tells you what happens to the volume of an element transported along a geodesic. A zero Ricci tensor simply does not mean the spacetime is flat.

Answer (score 4):

Ricci flat is not necessarily "truly" flat. Minkowski space has the entire Riemann curvature tensor vanishing, ie, $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=0$. However, being just Ricci flat is a weaker condition that only requires that the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$ vanish.

For example, Calabi-Yau manifolds are Ricci flat, but they are certainly not the same as Minkowski space.

Comment: Interestingly, for 2-dimensional manifolds, Ricci flatness and flatness are equivalent concepts.